# From Deore MTB to GRX Gravel

Tags: mountain-bike, gravel, grx

I want to convert my MTB to gravel, and the main issue for me is the transmission.
I plan to completely replace the transmission with 10x2, because it is pretty worn out. However, for me the main question is this: is it possible to use drop bars designed for 10 and 2 speeds respectively on a deore transmission?
Cassette M4100 11-42T
Rear Derailleur RD-M4120-SGS
Chain CN-HG54
Front Derailleur FD-M4100
Bottom Bracket SM-BB52

Comment: Is your frame size really suitable for a conversion to drop bars? Keep in mind that drop bars make the bike much “longer” so it usually only works with a frame which is one or two sizes too small and a short stem.

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, but if you want to use MTB components with brifters, this guide is comprehensive: https://bikepacking.com/gear/guide-to-mullet-drivetrains/

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to find compatible Shimano drop bar shifters 10-speed Shimano MTB derailleurs. The MTB and road groupsets are not compatible for 10 speed and higher.

I suggest [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31885/which-road-shifters-will-work-with-shimano-deore-m610-groupset) for more details about your options for shifters compatible with 10-speed Deore. You also have to think about the compatibility with your brakes, which is not given.

You also won't be able to put Shimano road and GRX cranks on 73 mm bottom brackets and you will have issues with proper fit of your frame. If it fits you with flat bars, it may fit poorly with drop bars.